# passing parameters through middlewares in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have a problem with passing parameters through several middlewares in express
this is one of my middlewares :

```
exports.checkParentReqs=async(req,res,next)=>{
try {
    const reqExist = await ParentReqsToConnect.find({ email: req.user.email }).populate({
        path: 'userId',
        select: 'firstName lastName'
    })
    req.parentReqs = reqExist
    next()
    console.log(req.parentReqs)
   
} catch (error) {
    next (new Error (error.message))
  
}
```

}

and this is the middleware chain in a specific route that includes above middleware:

```
    router
.route('/feed/getFeed')
.post(
    AuthController.protect,
    AuthController.isStudent,
    NewsController.getGoogleNews,
    TransactionsForFeedController.getRecentTransactions,
    TransactionsForFeedController.totalSpendingLimitsAlert,
    TransactionsForFeedController.categorizedSpendingLimitsAlert,
    BehavioralItemController.createTaskBihavioral,
    BehavioralItemController.createBankBihavioral,
    BehavioralItemController.createCompareUniBihavioral,
    BehavioralItemController.createConnectionBihavioral,
    BehavioralItemController.createPrivBudgetBihavioral,
    AlertController.ownUniAlert,
    AlertController.uniBudgetAlert,
    AlertController.uniBudgetSetPeriodAlert,
    AlertController.accountsAlert,
    AlertController.connectionAlert,
    AlertController.getAlerts,
    ParentReqsToConnectController.checkParentReqs,
    TaskController.getTasksForFeed,
    FeedController.getFeed,
    )
```

the third one from the end is above middleware.
and this is the last middleware FeedController.getFeed :

```
exports.getFeed = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.parentReqs)

        const feed = [
            ...req.tasks,
            ...req.transactions,
            ...req.news,
            req.privBudgetBehavioral,
            req.bankBehavioral,
            req.connectionBehavioral,
            req.taskBehavioral,
            req.compareUniBehavioral,
            ...req.parentReqs,
            ...req.alerts


        ].filter(item => item != null)
        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            feed
        })

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(401).json({
            status: 'failed',
            message:e.message
        })
    }
}
```

but req.parentReqs is not working in the getFeed function. the console.log inside getFeed gives me "undefined" while req.parentReqs inside ParentReqsToConnectController.checkParentReqs in not undefined.
seems it cant be transferred through middlewares

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: all the middlewares have the acess to a same req object, So the property you set in one middleware should be acessible on another middleware too. What about the second to last middleware? It could be possible that you may have altered parentReqs there.

Comment: This is a very strange way to structure your application. Have you considered just pulling in this data from the controller, instead of multiple dependent middlewares?

Comment: the strange thing about this is that some times the last one gets the req params that i've passed but some times not! the same situation for the second to last middleware.

Comment: if I want to run all these functions from getFeed controller, it will be so messy and unclean with irrelevant functions to it